# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

When I declared `async` function twice this error is occurring:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) in React Native

Category.jsx

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import Heading from "../../Component/Heading";
import GlobalApi from "../../Utils/GlobalApi";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Categories() {
  useEffect(() => {
    getCategories();
  }, []);

  const getCategories = () => {
    GlobalApi.getCategories()
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log("resp", resp.categories);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Heading text={"Categories"} isViewAll={true} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

API class

```js
import { request, gql } from "graphql-request";

const MASTER_URL =
  "https://api-ap-south-1.hygraph.com/v2/clrud3zbv0zjm01w12p1qw5x8/master";

const getSlider = async () => {
  const query = gql`
    query GetSlider {
      sliders {
        id
        name
        image {
          url
        }
      }
    }
  `;
  const result = await request(MASTER_URL, query);
  return result;
};

const getCategories = async () => {
  const query = gql`
    query GetCategory {
      categories {
        id
        name
        icon {
          url
        }
      }
  `;
  const result = await request(MASTER_URL, query);
  return result;
};

export default {
  getSlider,
  getCategories,
};
```

I tried everything and I can't resolve this problem. I tried by creating new class and called the API, but I still get that error or warning.

Answer (score 0):

Both the `getSlider` and `getCategories` functions return a Promise object, and Promises, other than the active pending status, can ***only ever*** resolve or reject. Your code just needs to add handling rejected promises or if there are any thrown exceptions during the Promise chain execution.

```js
const getCategories = () => {
  GlobalApi.getCategories()
    .then((resp) => {
      console.log("resp", resp.categories);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // catch and handle/ignore/etc any rejected Promise or thrown error
    });
};
```

or converted to `async/await` with `try/catch`

```js
const getCategories = async () => {
  try {
    const resp = await GlobalApi.getCategories();
    console.log("resp", resp.categories);
  } catch(error) {
    // catch and handle/ignore/etc any rejected Promise or thrown error
  };
};
```